# Excluding posts with certain tag from blogpage

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, blogs

I have succeeded in excluding certain categories from my blogpage by editing the function.php, however i cannot seem to exclude all posts with tag id 113 from my blog. Can anyone help me out by pointing out which code i should use?
Thanks in advance,
Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the code:

```
if(!has_tag(113))
{
  //Display your posts
}
```

The above code should be used inside the Wordpress loop.

==> In order to filter your posts inside **functions.php** you can use "**pre_get_posts**" hook:

```
function exclude_tag($query)
{
    if ($query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('tag__not_in', array( '113' ));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_tag');
```

Comment: For the people reading this, i wanted to change it to only hide posts from the home page, not from the search results. So i editted a bit:                   function exclude_tag($query)
{
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('tag__not_in', array(113,116));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_tag');